# Iterating Hashtable in Java (puzzle)

Tags: java, hashtable

So here's the conundrum:

"kb" is an instance of a class that extends java.util.Hashtable
The key is a String, the stored value is of a class called "IntelCard"

This code extracts the keys, and endeavors to print data from the table

```
    Set<String> ks = kb.keySet();
    System.out.println(ks); // is this what we thought?
    for(String key: ks){
        IntelCard ic = kb.get(key);
        String o = String.format("%-24s %24s %8s", 
                          ic.name, ic.alliance, ic.might);
        System.out.println(o);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
[commanderv, repo, olaf, triguy]
triguy                                  galactica    10000
triguy                                  galactica    10000
triguy                                  galactica    10000
triguy                                  galactica    10000
```

We can see the dump of "ks" which is supposed to be the set of keys. But apparently it is selecting only the last "touched" entry in the Hashtable. (In this test, "triguy" was the last value added.)

Is there a need to reset the Hashtable selector somehow? It doesn't make sense, since the code selects each value by key. Is there a need to reset the selector on the key set (ks)? That doesn't make sense either since the loop should simply iterate over the entire set.

I dunno, what am I missing?

---v

Comment: this code seems fine, maybe the code that sets the values has a problem. can you post that?

Comment: Post the code that adds values to hashtable

Comment: It seems you have added same value to all four keys, are you sure you have added different intel card instances

Comment: You said, kb is an instance of a class that extends Hashtable. Could we see that code, please? Maybe there is a problem with the put operation in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have the same `IntelCard` object associated to multiple keys; to be sure you are iterating over all keys, format string using `String.format(key, ic.alliance, ic.might)`.
Iterate over map using `Map.Entry<K,V>` instead of using `keySet()/get()` pair:

```
for(final Map.Entry<String,IntelCard> e : kb.entrySet()) {
  IntelCard ic = e.getValue();
  String o = String.format("%-24s %24s %8s", ic.name, ic.alliance, ic.might);
  System.out.println(o);
}
```

Comment: First response, and kudos for the helpful diagnostic stanza. All four answers posted within about 2 mins of each other were correct. It was the data setter that was flawed.  By returning to that code and initializing the input buffer before setting it into the Hashtable, the problem was solved. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you added 4 similar (same toString() of fields) IntelCards with different keys. Hashtable has unique keys, not necessarily unique values.